# What is the correct representation of memory data?

Tags: python, memory

I am trying to represent:

```
bar = [[7,2,6],[3,4,8]]
```

As a memory diagram to illustrate how the numbers are stored in memory with each box being a memory deposit (I think), I would be much obliged if anyone could tell me the correct way of representing this? I am a beginner programming and currently I am not even sure what these sorts of diagrams are called so I'm not sure what to search for online to find more information.

[image]

Comment: The Python language does not specify this — it varies in different implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this. Check out this [vizualizer](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit):

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!!! Thank you so much

Comment: @sesrkuse you are welcome. please accept the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: Ok I gladly will, I have to wait a few minutes to do that apparently, do you know if the 'bar' box would have to be split in two or if it would be whole?

Comment: `bar` is basically just an pointer to an list object containing 2 elements. these two elements are also two lists with 3 elements each. so bar itself is a single box

Comment: Great, thanks ever so much